# Does this layout module already exist in Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to make my CSS as modular as possible following the SMACSS principals. I have a layout that I use again and again so I wanted to make a CSS module for it. Below is what I have.

Its a 2 colum full width liquid layout where the first colum takes up as much space as it can the second colum takes out as little as possible.

```
<div class="table-layout-cont-new">
   <div class="table-layout-col-1-new">
     <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-default-new" placeholder="400">
   </div>
   <div class="table-layout-col-2-new">
     <a class="form-tooltip-new glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" href="#">
        <span class="sr-only">Information</span>
     </a>
    </div>
  </div>

input {
  width: 100%;
}


.table-layout-cont-new {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-layout-col-1-new {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.table-layout-col-2-new {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaWRKe

Im using Twitter Bootstrap 3. Are there any classes already provided that do the same thing?

Comment: The [input group addons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) do something similar to what you want. You could also just put a class of `pull-right` on the second column to float it to the right of the first.

Comment: I dont want to have the layout to have any styling of its own. Also ive used it for laying out loads of different elements, not just forms. I need it to be independent from forms.

Comment: If you don't want to/can't use `pull-right` class then I can't think of anything else in bootstrap that would have the same effect. Think what you have is probably your best option.

Comment: Well what im doing isnt floating to the right.

Comment: I know, but floating to the right would do essentially the same thing in most situations. As I said, if that doesn't work for you then I can't think of anything else.

Comment: "SMACKS" You mean SMACSS?